# Docker Run Multiple Host Port Not Working

Tags: docker

I'm running:

```
docker run -p 4000-4100:4000 <image>
```

To get something like

```
0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp
0.0.0.0:4001->4000/tcp
0.0.0.0:4002->4000/tcp
...
```

But instead, I'm getting just the 1st line

```
0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp
```

However if I do

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 -p 4001:4000 -p 4002:4000 ... <image>
```

The output is the one expected, but of course, I don't want to write that `n` times. Any workaround would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`docker run --publish=4000-4100:4000-4100 <image>`

The ranges need only be equivalently sized:

`docker run --publish=4000-4100:8800-8900 <image>`

Be aware, of course, that each 1:1 port mapping must be programmed in iptables and so, the larger the range, the longer the time to do so.

Comment: Not only an iptables entry, but also a docker-proxy process per port.

Comment: I did not know that